# Any way to customize the input delimiter for fileinput.input?

Tags: python, input, readline, delimiter, file-io

Can anyone think of a way to change the input delimiter for the [**`fileinput.input`**](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) method?

(According to the docs, the default input delimiter is `'\n'`, and it is not stripped.)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to those docs? I can't find anything that says that here: http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html

Comment: fileinput uses `file.readline()` in which `\n` is hardcoded.

Comment: @thg435: do you have a link to the source code you're referring to?